# argument list for class template "std::array" is missing

Tags: c++, inference, onnx

I tried to follow the tutorial of ONNX C++ interence:

https://github.com/ilpropheta/onnxruntime-demo/blob/master/OnnxRuntimeDemo/Linear.cpp

I got 17 errors when I tried to build C++ app console. I noticed the main error is revelent to array. The code E0441 shows

> argument list for class template "std::array" is missing. Support needed

```
#include "Linear.h"
#include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void Demo::RunLinearRegression()
{
    // gives access to the underlying API (you can optionally customize log)
    // you can create one environment per process (each environment manages an internal thread pool)
    Ort::Env env;

    // creates an inference session for a certain model
    Ort::Session session{ env, LR"(linear.onnx)", Ort::SessionOptions{} };

    // Ort::Session gives access to input and output information:
    // - count
    // - name
    // - shape and type
    std::cout << "Number of model inputs: " << session.GetInputCount() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of model outputs: " << session.GetOutputCount() << "\n";

    // you can customize how allocation works. Let's just use a default allocator provided by the library
    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;
    // get input and output names
    auto* inputName = session.GetInputName(0, allocator);
    std::cout << "Input name: " << inputName << "\n";

    auto* outputName = session.GetOutputName(0, allocator);
    std::cout << "Output name: " << outputName << "\n";

    // get input shape
    auto inputShape = session.GetInputTypeInfo(0).GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetShape();
    // set some input values
    std::vector<float> inputValues = { 4, 5, 6 };

    // where to allocate the tensors
    auto memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtDeviceAllocator, OrtMemTypeCPU);

    // create the input tensor (this is not a deep copy!)
    auto inputOnnxTensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(memoryInfo,
        inputValues.data(), inputValues.size(),
        inputShape.data(), inputShape.size());

    // the API needs the array of inputs you set and the array of outputs you get
    array inputNames = { inputName };
    array outputNames = { outputName };

    // finally run the inference!
    auto outputValues = session.Run(
        Ort::RunOptions{ nullptr }, // e.g. set a verbosity level only for this run
        inputNames.data(), &inputOnnxTensor, 1, // input to set
        outputNames.data(), 1);                 // output to take 

    // extract first (and only) output
    auto& output1 = outputValues[0];
    const auto* floats = output1.GetTensorMutableData<float>();
    const auto floatsCount = output1.GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo().GetElementCount();

    // just print the output values
    std::copy_n(floats, floatsCount, ostream_iterator<float>(cout, " "));


    // closing boilerplate
    allocator.Free(inputName);
    allocator.Free(outputName);
}
```

Comment: `array inputNames = { inputName };` -- Do you see anything wrong or strange about this line of code?  Are you aware that `std::array` is a template class, just like `std::vector`?  Now compare how you declared `vector`, and how you are declaring `array`.

Comment: what is the type of `inputName` and `outputName`?

Comment: I follow the youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exsgNLf-MyY&t=2166s, I am quite new in C++ and ONNX, the tutorial seems no need to change anything for array inputNames, arrayouputNames. Support and comment needed.

Comment: @Adelyn You do realize that frameworks, libraries, etc. require you to know the computer language you will be using when using the framework and/or library.  Trying to learn C++ at the same time you're using a library is not a good path.  C++ by itself is one of the most difficult languages to learn, and it can't be learned by picking up code off the Internet.  The error is obvious *if* you understood what templates are.

Comment: Video hostings are good places for sharing knowledge, but not good enough for teaching. Prefer studying C++ by books.

Answer (score -2):

Just change `array` to `std::vector<const char*>` for both `inputNames` and `outputNames`.

std::array does not work because it requires a type and array size in the declaration [check this docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

so to make std::array works, you need to declare it as following:

`std::array<std::string, 1>  inputNames = {inputName}`

Comment: i downvoted becuase it doesnt explain why the array declaration didnt work

Comment: @pm100 updated with explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).